# Show parent_model in django template

Tags: python, django

I have a variable:

```
m2m_links = mymodel._meta.many_to_many
```

This has all of the fields that are m2m in a particular model.  I want the template to display the names of the models that are linked.  Within my view, I can list the tables like so:

```
for f in m2m_links:
    print f.related.parent_model
```

But in my template, if I try

```
{% for table in m2m_links %}
    {{ table.related.parent_model }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

I get an error: "Caught DoesNotExist while rendering"

How do I get the names of the tables to render in the template?  And a further question, how do I get just the name, not something like

```
<class 'myapp.models.ModelName'>
```

which is what I have showing in my terminal from the "print" statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason, based on the template code you've provided that you should be getting that error. Most likely, there's something else going on in your template that is causing that.

As for your second question, the way to get a class' name is:

```
some_class.__name__
```

However, the Django template engine will not allow you to use underscored properties in the template, so your best bet is to prepare a proper list in your view:

```
linked_models = [m2m.related.parent_model.__name__ for m2m in mymodel._meta.many_to_many]
```

Then, just loop through that in your template and the all the work is already done.

**UPDATE (based on comment)**

You do it mostly the same way, though you have a couple of choices.

1. You can do a list of tuples and unpack it in the template:

   ```
   linked_models = [(m2m.related.parent_model.__name__, m2m.related.parent_model._meta.verbose_name) for m2m in mymodel._meta.many_to_many]
   ```

   Then, in your template:

   ```
   {% for class_name, verbose_name in linked_models %}
       {{ class_name }} {{ verbose_name }}
   {% endfor %}
   ```
2. Create a list of dictionaries and reference the keys in the template:

   ```
   linked_models = [{'class_name': m2m.related.parent_model.__name__, 'verbose_name': m2m.related.parent_model._meta.verbose_name} for m2m in mymodel._meta.many_to_many]
   ```

   Them, in your template:

   ```
   {% for model in linked_models %}
       {{ model.class_name }} {{ model.verbose_name }}
   {% endfor %}
   ```

Comment: This is great, thanks.  What if, in addition though, I was using the .verbose_name attribute?  for table in m2m_links: print table.verbose_name.  Can I have your linked_models contain not only the .related.parent_model.__name__ but also the .verbose_name?